# How to add a progress bar to windows form which shows dynamically how much process is completed

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio

I am working on a Windows Form in Visual Studio.

The form takes 2 excel files (say A.xlsx und B.xlsx), processes them and produces "n" number of files at the end.

The "n" is always "total number of sheets in A.xlsx minus 2"

How can I program a progress bar in the windows form which shows the progress (% Complete) ?

```
private void progressBarTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int progressBarValue = 0;
            progressBarValue += 1;
            lblprogressBar.Text = progressBarValue.ToString() + "% complete";
            progressBar.Value = progressBarValue;

            if(progressBarValue>= progressBar.Maximum)
            {
                progressBarTimer.Stop();
            }
        }
```

I've tried the above block but I don't know where to include this block in windows form. This block is currently in Form.cs. I have very less experience working with windows Forms in Visual Studio. Any help is ver much appreciated.

Comment: I'd try a web-search for "winforms progress bar tutorial", e.g. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/449594/Progress-Bars-Threads-Windows-Forms-and-You

Comment: Is there any update in this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems you need to solve.

1. How to measure the progress
2. How to show the progress

To measure the progress you need whatever method that is doing the work to tell how it is going. The typical way to do this would be to take a [IProgress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iprogress-1.report?source=recommendations&view=net-7.0) parameter in your method. I usually prefer to use a double in the 0-1 range for progress.

```
public void MyMethod(IProgress<double> progress){
  for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
    progress.Report( i / (double)count);
  }
}
```

You will need to run this method on a background thread to ensure the UI can update smoothly. If you lack any such loop where you can report progress, you might just have to use an indeterminate progress-bar and accept that you have no idea when the work will complete.

To do the actual update you would typically register an event handler on the [ProgressChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1.progresschanged?view=net-7.0) event for the shared progress object. This should also ensure that the UI is only updated on the UI thread.

```
public void MyProgressEventHandler(object sender, double progress){
    lblprogressBar.Text = (progress * 100).ToString("0.#") + "% complete";
    progressBar.Value = progressBar.Minimum + progressBar.Maximum * progress;
    progressBar.Invalidate(); // don't know if this is needed or not
}
```